# GLFW directory not found with CMake and vcpkg

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, glfw, vcpkg

I have been unable to figure out how to get CMake to find and set correct GLFW CMake constants when using CMake in VS2017. Any help will be greatly appreciated :).

I downloaded `glfw3` through Microsoft's `vcpkg` tool. I have checked that files do physically exist in the directory that `vcpkg` puts them in (`~\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include`). I set up my `CMakeSettings.json` as per their docs [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/examples/using-sqlite.md). I used that tutorial as a basis for getting GLFW to be set up correctly.

I then use `find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)` to find the `glfw3` library. This does not spit out any errors. Actually the `CMakeLists.txt` doesn't complain at all. It's at the compile stage where it complains.

After that I add `glfw3` with `target_link_libraries(exe ${GLFW3_LIBRARIES})` to the executable.

Then when I try and build a simple example (including the header file), the compilation fails because it cannot find `GLFW/glfw3.h`.

The error from MSVC:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GLFW/glfw3.h': No such file or directory
```

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt` for added reference:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(learn-opengl)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)

add_executable(learn-opengl main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(learn-opengl ${GLFW3_LIBRARIES})
```

`GLFW3_LIBRARIES` I got from `glfw3Config.cmake` by snooping around what `vcpkg` puts in the installed directory (`~\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\share\glfw3`)

And just in case, the `main.cpp`:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried calling `cmake` from the command line as well, but to no avail that didn't work either.

Am I missing something? Did I perhaps misunderstand something in `vcpkg` documentation? I have really no idea what I am missing... :/ I should say, in addition, that I am fairly new to CMake as well.

Comment: Can you add the imported target `glfw` or `glfw3` to your `target_link_libraries` command instead of `${GLFW3_LIBRARIES}`? That should fix the error you see.

Comment: @vre OMG! `glfw` worked :D! Would you kindly post your comment as a answer so I can close the question? Thanks so much! So simple...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reformulating my previous comment as answer:

You should add the imported target `glfw` to your `target_link_libraries` command instead of `${GLFW3_LIBRARIES}`.
The `find_package(glfw3)` generates an import target `glfw`. By making your target `learn-opengl` dependent on this imported target you specify both the library to link with and the include directories to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `.\vcpkg integrate project` in your vcpkg directory, and it'll give you some instructions to install vcpkg with nuget, follow those, and you can just put `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` in your cpp file